# AngualrJS ElasticUI dependency injection

Tags: angularjs

I have a question regarding dependency injection in Angular.

I'm using ElasticUI:
https://github.com/YousefED/ElasticUI

The index-name needs to be set inside the  tag.

```
<body ng-app="tutorial" eui-index="'INDEX_NAME'">
```

Is it possible to set that INDEX_NAME from "outside" ?

```
angular.module('tutorial', ['elasticui']). ???
```

I don't know much about Angular. I'm sorry if this is a stupid question...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just like passing a value to a directive. In your controller:

```
.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.indexName = "asdsd";
})
```

In the HTML:

```
<body ng-app="tutorial" ng-controller="MyController" eui-index="indexName">
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the index name in "IndexVM" instance and then do refresh for the interface. Below is the code for it:

```
.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.IndexName="abc";
    $scope.changeIndexName(field);   
    $scope.indexVM.index=$scope.IndexName; 
    $scope.indexVM.refresh(false);
});
```

Comment: Saved me a ton of time man, I was attacking this at the euiIndex directive level with no luck. The accepted answer, while it makes sense, did NOT work for me due to the lack of refresh. Thanks!